# Is the Mayan/Templar Armour just cosmetic?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

Unlike in *Assassin's Creed 2*, your health increases when you craft items and all the outfits you can obtain seem to be just cosmetic.

Since the Mayan/Templar Armour are equipped from the same menu as all the other outfits, do they have any in-game benefits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mayan and Templar armors do give special benefits.

- The Mayan Armor deflects all ranged attacks
- The Templar Armor reduces
  all damage by 25%

other armors that have benefits

- Stealth outfit - you can hide better, enemies won't detect you as easily.
- Hunter outfit -  reduces range of detection from animals

The other armors are all cosmetic, though.

Answer (score -1):

They are not purely cosmetic.

**1. Mayan Outfit**

Ability to help deflect incoming metal projectiles (bullets).

[image]

**2. Templar Armor**

Increased resistance against enemy attacks.

[image]

**3. Stealth Outfit**

Decreased detection of enemies (makes you more stealthy).

[image]

In addition, the **hunter outfit** reduces range of detection of animals.